# I want to sort value in pivot using pandas at multilevel

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sorting, pivot

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['John', 'Boby', 'Mina', 'Peter', 'Nicky'],
      'B': ['Pune', 'Mumbai', 'Pune', 'Mumbai', 'Pune'],
      'C': [27, 23, 21, 25, 24]})

      A      B      C
0   John    Pune    27
1   Boby    Mumbai  23
2   Mina    Pune    21
3   Peter   Mumbai  25
4   Nicky   Pune    24


   
table = pd.pivot_table(df, values ='C', index =['B', 'A'],
                          aggfunc = np.sum)
table


                C
  B      A  
Mumbai  Boby    23
        Peter   25
Pune    John    27
        Mina    21
        Nicky   24
```

I want to sort this pivot 'B' groupwise summation in descending order.Here as pune have (27+21+24) 72 numbers which is greater than mumbai(23+25=48)
SO pune should be at level 1 and mumbai.

Again in Pune group it should be in s=descending order .i.e John,Nicky and then Mina
in Mumbai group peter and Boby.

There could be many values in B

required output:

```
               C
  B      A  
Pune    John    27
        Nicky   24
        Mina    21
Mumbai Peter    25
        Boby    23
```

Answer (score 0):

Create helper level with aggregated values and use it for sorting with first level:

```
#simplify solution - aggregate sum for all numeric columns
table = df.groupby(['B', 'A']).sum()

table = (table.set_index(table.groupby(level=0)['C'].transform('sum'), append=True)
              .sort_index(level=[-1,0], ascending=[False, True])
              .droplevel(-1))
print (table)
               C
B      A        
Pune   John   27
       Mina   21
       Nicky  24
Mumbai Boby   23
       Peter  25
```

Comment: what if i have many columns in between like i have columns ['B','F','A','C']

Comment: @anjalijoshi - It si sorting by column `C` ? If many columns sorting is different?

Comment: sorting by column C only butt in between i have many columns

Comment: @anjalijoshi - Then solution working well.